# How did Bhishma get the name of "Bhishma"?

Tags: mahabharata

Bhishma's birth name was Devavrata and he was called Gangeya and Gangaputra because he was son of Ganga but why Bhishma is named as "Bhishma"?  What does Bhishma mean?

Comment: Please don’t ask questions and answers unnecessarily only for votes. It’s not encouraged. We know you’ve read sacred texts / if not please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devavrata (देवव्रत) is his real name.

His other names are

GaṅgāPutra (गंगापुत्र) - son of Ganga (Purity)

Śāṅtanava (शान्तनव) - son of Śāṅtanu

Gaurāṅga (गौरांग) - the one with fair body

Śvetavīra (श्वेतवीर) - a white warrior or the one who is heroic white

Bhīṣma (भीष्म) - one who undertakes a terrible vow(Bhīṣaṇa Pratijñā)

Bhishma is one of the portion of Vasus

According to Monier Monier-Williams, the word Bhishma (भीष्म) means 'terrible', 'horrible', 'fearful' or 'fierce'. The word is also used to describe Rudra, the fierce Vedic god, as well as the Rakshasa.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/gangaputra

Answer (score 1):

Bhishma means terrible. The birth name of Bhishma was actually Devavrata meaning devoted to gods and also Gangeya.

> Ye kings, I have already relinquished my right to the throne, I shall now settle the matter of my children. O fisherman, from this day I adopt the vow of Brahmacharya (study and meditation in celibacy). If I die sonless, I shall yet attain to regions of perennial bliss in heaven!'

Bhishma took a terrible vow of celibacy.

The gods later named him Bhishma

> 'Upon these words of the son of Ganga, the hair on the fisherman's body stood on end from glee, and he replied, 'I bestow my daughter!' Immediately after, the Apsaras and the gods with diverse tribes of Rishis began to rain down flowers from the firmament upon the head of Devavrata and exclaimed, 'This one is Bhishma (the terrible).' Bhishma then, to serve his father, addressed the illustrious damsel and said, 'O mother, ascend this chariot, and let us go unto our house.'

https://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Adi_Parva_Chapter_100:5

That is the proof

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.